# How are you meant to format a query string without using key and value?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using a get request to process a search query -- imagine having a search box on the front end to find relevant messages that contain the words given in the search box. My route looks something like this

`api/messages/search/?foo%20bar`

When I try to handle this on the back end it seems that it is always expecting me to have given it some kind of key-value pair.

What is the appropriate way to handle this kind of query? I want to be able to split the words in the query on `%20` and then iterate over them thusly.

What am I missing?

Comment: How about use post or setting your route?

Comment: `%20` denotes `space`, what exactly you are trying to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "When I try to handle this on the back end it seems that it is always
>   expecting me to have given it some kind of key-value pair."

This is correct, because you used the "?" sign you must provide key value pairs after. A query string must have named parameters

```
api/messages/search/?myString=foo%20bar
```

See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string